# Export a related list of size > 100 to Excel

Tags: visualforce, excel

I am trying to create a custom link that will export a related list directly to Excel. Right now I can't get it to export more than 100 names regardless of the size of the list. Is there a way I can work around this?

```
<apex:page standardController="Lists__c",  contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Influencers">   
        <apex:relatedList pageSize="1000" list="List_Contact_Associations_del__r"  />
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Lists__c.List_Contact_Associations_del__r}" var="mycontact">    
       <apex:column value="{!mycontact.id}" ></apex:column>
       <apex:column value="{!mycontact.Name}" ></apex:column>   
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

HELP Article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000025257&type=1

The maximum number of rows that you can use when using `apex:relatedList` is 100. My suggestion would be to create a custom related list component that is not limited to this where you can then output as much as you like. Above is a link to some docs that outlines the limit here for using `apex:relatedList`.

Comment: @BrooksJohnson you're welcome